# Main class could not be found and more

Tags: java

I have just began learning Java and have been running into the same problem for three days. To learn I have been reading through the java tutorials provided by  Oracle. I am trying to perform the exercises at the end of of one of the lessons that go as so:

> 1) Create new classes for each real-world object that you observed at the beginning of this trail.
>   2) For each new class that you've created above, create an interface that defines its behavior, then require your class to implement it.

I have been writing my code in Netbeans IDE 8.1 on Windows 10. But every time I try to run my code I get an error saying that my main class has not been found.

Here is the code that I used for my class:

```
package practice;


public class Car implements Acura {

int speed = 2;
int gear = 1;
int gas = 100;
  }   


public void SpeedUp (int increment){
    speed = speed + 48;
    }

public void ChangeGear (int NewValue){
    gear = 4;
    }

public void UseGas (int decrement){
    gas = gas - 5;
    }

public void printStates(){
    System.out.println(
    "Car Speed:" + speed + "Gear:" + gear + "Gas:" + gas
    )
   }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

And here is the code I used for my interface:

```
package practice;

public interface Acura {

    void SpeedUp (int increment);

    void ChangGear (int NewValue);

    void UseGas (int decrement);

}
```

So my first question is: **Why do I keep getting an error message saying that the main class could not be found?**

And just for the record, I have tried multiple solutions (seriously, a lot...) over the last three days and none of them have worked. But I will not list these solutions in the hope that a new answer is given or that I did not try them or read them correctly.

And my second question is: **Is my code causing this error to reoccur?** If someone could proofread and correct my code above that would be greatly appreciated!

I have just started learning Java and I would love to move on to a different topic as it has been a whole 3 days! But I can't let this problem go unsolved before I progress. So if anyone could help me out here I really would appreciate it!

Comment: There is some really weird placement of brackets in that code.

Comment: The `main` method must be *inside* the class. If you fix your indentations, it'll become obvious that it is current outside (aka *after*) the class.

Comment: Not related to your question but... you have some oddities such as creating an interface related to a specific car, then implementing a generic car from it (you're backward on that concept); passing parameters to all your methods, then ignoring them and using a hard-coded value (such as acceleration and gas usage), etc.

Comment: Extending what @Andreas said: You actually have *nothing* in your class except for some int properties. All of your methods are outside of the `Car` class, not just `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These should work, made a few corrections:

```
public class Car implements Acura {

    int speed = 2;
    int gear = 1;
    int gas = 100;

    public void speedUp (int increment) {
        speed = speed + 48;
    }

    public void changeGear (int newValue) {
        gear = 4;
    }

    public void useGas (int decrement) {
        gas = gas - 5;
    }

    public void printStates() {
        System.out.println( "Car Speed: " + speed + "Gear: " + gear + "Gas: " + gas);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    }

}
```

and

```
public interface Acura {

    void speedUp (int increment);

    void changeGear (int newValue);

    void useGas (int decrement);

}
```

Comment: @m0skit0 indeed. All method parameters for the methods from `Acura` are unused, and the `printStates` method will produce unseparated text.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that my code is terrible but it's apart of the process. How exactly do I call on the printStates to print out the car speed, gear, ect.?

Comment: No problem, your code isn't terrible but it could be improved. It will come with practice. It depends on how you are running your program, you could call it in the main method like `printStates();`